# r derived indicator variable

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose this is my dataset.

```
ID   Group   Col1     Col2   
1    A       1.49     NA
2    A       0.12     NA
2    A       NA       0.35
3    B       NA       0.87
4    B       NA       0.64
4    B       NA       0.43
5    C       1.53     NA
5    C       0.38     NA
6    C       71.92    NA
7    D       0.25     0.88
7    D       0.92     0.10
7    D       NA       0.53
7    D       NA       0.60
```

How do I create a derived indicator variable column like this.

```
ID   Group   Col1     Col2      Col_I

1    A       1.49     NA        Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive
2    A       0.12     NA        Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive 
2    A       NA       0.35      Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive

3    B       NA       0.87      Only Col2
4    B       NA       0.64      Only Col2
4    B       NA       0.43      Only Col2

5    C       1.53     NA        Only Col1
5    C       0.38     NA        Only Col1
6    C       71.92    NA        Only Col1

7    D       0.25     0.88      Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
7    D       0.92     0.10      Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
7    D       NA       0.53      Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
7    D       NA       0.60      Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
```

The indicator column `Col_I` is at Group level
This indicator column indicates if the values in Col1, Col2 are mutually exclusive or overlap or Only Col1 or Only Col2.

I have an idea how to do this but it is very clunky and ineffective. So any suggestions or advice is much apricated.

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), 
                       Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D"), 
                       Col1 = c(1.49, 0.12, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.53, 0.38, 71.92, 0.25, 0.92, NA, NA), 
                       Col2 = c(NA, NA, 0.35, 0.87, 0.64, 0.43, NA, NA, NA, 0.88, 0.1, 0.53, 0.6)), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your example data you could use:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "ID   Group   Col1     Col2   
1    A       1.49     NA
2    A       0.12     NA
2    A       NA       0.35
3    B       NA       0.87
4    B       NA       0.64
4    B       NA       0.43
5    C       1.53     NA
5    C       0.38     NA
6    C       71.92    NA
7    D       0.25     0.88
7    D       0.92     0.10
7    D       NA       0.53
7    D       NA       0.60  ",
header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Col_I = case_when(all(!is.na(Col1)) & all(is.na(Col2)) ~ "Only Col1",
                           all(is.na(Col1)) & all(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Only Col2",
                           sum(!is.na(coalesce(Col1, Col2))) == length(Col1) &
                             sum(!is.na(Col1)) + sum(!is.na(Col2)) == length(Col1) ~ "Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive",
                           sum(!is.na(Col1)) > sum(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, Col1 majority",
                           sum(!is.na(Col1)) < sum(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority",
                           TRUE ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, no majority")) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#>       ID Group  Col1  Col2 Col_I                            
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                            
#>  1     1 A      1.49 NA    Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  2     2 A      0.12 NA    Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  3     2 A     NA     0.35 Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  4     3 B     NA     0.87 Only Col2                        
#>  5     4 B     NA     0.64 Only Col2                        
#>  6     4 B     NA     0.43 Only Col2                        
#>  7     5 C      1.53 NA    Only Col1                        
#>  8     5 C      0.38 NA    Only Col1                        
#>  9     6 C     71.9  NA    Only Col1                        
#> 10     7 D      0.25  0.88 Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 11     7 D      0.92  0.1  Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 12     7 D     NA     0.53 Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 13     7 D     NA     0.6  Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
```

Using `xor` as suggested by MrFlick:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Col_I = case_when(all(!is.na(Col1)) & all(is.na(Col2)) ~ "Only Col1",
                           all(is.na(Col1)) & all(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Only Col2",
                           all(xor(is.na(Col1), is.na(Col2))) ~ "Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive",
                           sum(!is.na(Col1)) > sum(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, Col1 majority",
                           sum(!is.na(Col1)) < sum(!is.na(Col2)) ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority",
                           TRUE ~ "Col1, Col2 overlap, no majority")) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#>       ID Group  Col1  Col2 Col_I                            
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                            
#>  1     1 A      1.49 NA    Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  2     2 A      0.12 NA    Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  3     2 A     NA     0.35 Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive    
#>  4     3 B     NA     0.87 Only Col2                        
#>  5     4 B     NA     0.64 Only Col2                        
#>  6     4 B     NA     0.43 Only Col2                        
#>  7     5 C      1.53 NA    Only Col1                        
#>  8     5 C      0.38 NA    Only Col1                        
#>  9     6 C     71.9  NA    Only Col1                        
#> 10     7 D      0.25  0.88 Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 11     7 D      0.92  0.1  Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 12     7 D     NA     0.53 Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
#> 13     7 D     NA     0.6  Col1, Col2 overlap, Col2 majority
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: You could also do a `xor()` for the mutually exclusive case: `all(xor(is.na(Col1), is.na(Col2)))~"Col1, Col2 mutually exclusive"`

Comment: Yeah! That's the logic I was trying to figure out - thanks Mr Flick! I'll edit my answer

Comment: @jared_mamrot, and MrFlick, Thank you both. This was perfect.